# How can I apply CSS in Lightning Buttons to change color

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, lightning, aura-framework

I have applied css to my lightning Button to change the color of it. And I have class named Morning inside my button

```
.THIS.Morning{
    //Mornig is class inside my button
    color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be good with the normal button variant, have you tried it? `<lightning:button variant="destructive-text"/>`
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:button/example

You can use normal `<button>` and style it with Salesforce-defined classes + whatever else you need. Use Lightning Design System: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/

If it absolutely has to be a `<lightning:button>` and variant's aren't enough - look into button "[styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/#Styling-Hooks-Overview)". More info:

- https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your CSS :

```
.THIS .slds-button_brand {
    color:red;
}
```